# Помогите составить SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с полями int А и int B. Мне нужно определить что в таблице есть записи где в одной записи A>0 и B<9. Но так же мне подойдет условие если в одной записи А>0, а в другой записи В<9. Оба условия должны быть выполнены в одной таблице.

таблица 1 (одна запись) - условие верно: A=1, B=5
таблица 2 (две записи) - условие верно: А=1, B=9 / A=0, B=3
таблица 3 (две записи) - условие не верно: А=0, B=9 / A=0, B=3
таблица 4 (две записи) - условие не верно: А=2, B=9 / A=7, B=9

Возможно это выполнить одним запросом? Достаточно только положительный count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 1
FROM table
HAVING SUM(A>0)*SUM(B<9)
```